# Logo and site design

Tags: discussion, design

Assalam O alaikum everyone and hurray! we have  made it. Now the next part is to make a logo and design of the site. Please provide fresh ideas for it. Thanks

Comment: It is too early! The design will stay this way (beta design) till be exit public beta and the site is launched. When the time comes [Jin](http://stackexchange.com/users/21721/jin) will contact us for ideas about the site's design.

Comment: the [meta-tag:support] tag is for asking help from SE regarding using the site.

Comment: It's kinda early for this. We won't get a design until we exit public beta successfully. Sometimes it takes months and months.

Comment: @ashes999 it doesn't hurt to get the design discussion started early :) So when the time comes, I'll have a lot of good references and suggestions from the community.

Comment: A relevant post (on this meta) by one of our Community Managers from last week: [Custom Islam Stack Exchange design and logo - Information gathering](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3576/46770) :)

Comment: Update: [Your new site design is live!](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3649/46770)

Answer (score 12):

Calligraphy is very popular in Islam. It would be awesome if we can have `لا إله إلا الله محمد رسول الله` written in calligraphy. Also, it would look good if we do a little calligraphy on the right and left corners of the site. Thanks

Comment: I support this idea. And I oppose the idea of using crescent moon symbol. Because it is not a symbol of Islam; actually there is no symbol of Islam. We can simple use the Tawheed word as you suggested.

Comment: Lol, do you mean 'calligraphy' instead of 'cryptography'? But some steganography in the images would be fun too :P

Comment: Edited ;)......

Answer (score 8):

I have new ideas about header and up-vote down-vote buttons. How about using the ornaments between surahs in a mushaf as a header, and write Islam in it in a arabic letters fashion. To illustrate what I mean, I used my superb graphic design skills and made this;

[image: header]

Ok, I know that looks really bad, but blame it on my lack of graphic ability. In the hands of an professional, the idea can turn out to be good.

And about up and down votes, why don't we use the ayah separators in mushafs? Something like this;

[image: vote buttons]

Inspecting the design in different mushaf could turn out to be a good idea in my opinion.

Comment: +1 Love the upvote downvote icons :)

Comment: The upvote and downvote icons are killers!!

Comment: but, didn't liked the header. Can I both up and downvote ? :P

Comment: Don't like the header, vote icons are cool...

Comment: above should be made into a light color header

Answer (score 4):

For the logo, I prefer the usage of tulip, crescent and calligraphy. Something like this for example: [image: Inspiration for logo]

And for site design, I prefer aquatic/light-blue/light-green color theme, as it feels relaxed and peaceful. For example, look at this (tulip is a bonus :P ):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In addition to using Arabic calligraphy as Start up Crazy has suggested for general styling, we should probably use a crescent for the logo of Islam.SE, as it is well recognized as a symbol for Islam that is also accepted by the vast majority of Muslims.

Comment: I personally avoid that symbol, if for no reason other than because the crescent can be used as fuel for that oh-so-annoying "Moon God" argument.

Comment: Eh, I wouldn't worry about fringe *theories* such as the Moon God thing. There will always be someone ready to latch unto something else.

Answer (score 3):

Asalamu wa alaikum,

I brought this question up in the chat, goldPseudo,yasar11732, and me worked something out.

Here is what goldPseudo said:

> In keeping with the calligraphy theme, I would lean towards making things look resemble a book; white to yellow "paper" color for the background, with fancy colorful calligraphy-borders.
>   Similar to what you'd find in a decent quality Qur'an.

Here is what Yasar said:

> I am for calligraphy + crescent + tulip :)

I kind of gone for a brownish color.

Comment: Why a tulip though?

Comment: in Turkey, it is very common that people use tulip in Islamic themes.  Like the crescent, it got adopted into Islamic iconography because the Ottoman Empire was the Islamic world for a good chunk of history.  By goldPseudo and Yasar

Comment: Ah I didn't know that. Now that you've mentioned it, it's true. I see tulips in all sorts of mosaics and the like. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For the color theme, I suggest using a light-green coloring with yellowish white background.

On the left hand side of We can put a logo.

#### Logo idea

We can use calligraphic writing of the Kalima Tawheed (La-ilaha-illallah..). The writing should be clear enough to be recognized the kaliman, meaning it should not be more art than it's message. I'm against rounding of the writing also. But, A half round circle writing may not be bad.

On top of the Kalima, We can use a palm tree and a crescent on the upper left side of the tree.

#### Vote buttons

For upvote and downvote icons, I pretty much liked [yasar's answer](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/61/177).

Answer (score 1):

In this answer, I am attempting to suggest what the logo and site design should be.  I am combining the already existing (and up-voted) suggestions into this one answer.  I intend to attempt to make this answer a full suggestion of what this site might look like entirely (every aspect of it).  If you like it please up-vote, if you think something needs adding then please either give a comment or (if you can) edit it.

### The Logo

I believe the logo should be the name Allah:

[image]

I pick this for a few reasons, one believing in Allah is the base of faith and Islam, every Muslim, no matter their sect must believe in Allah, this is one of the things all so called sects of Islam have in common (and to take it further, the believe in Allah/God is what all three Abrahamic faiths believe in). Secondly, Fahad Uddin, in His answer, mentioned that calligraphy is popular in Islam, so the above suggested logo/picture is a mild, easy to read (Insha'Allah) calligraphy form of the word Allah.

I think the logo should be in the middle of the site's header, with the following text (which I think should be a bit smaller than the width of the logo) under it:

```
Islam الاسلام
```

### The Tabs

What I mean by tabs is the **Questions**, **Tags**, **Users**, **Badges**, **Unanswered**, and **Ask Question** tabs.  I think, since the tabs are six all together, I think they should be split into three.  So what I mean is, they should be placed under the logo like this:

**Questions**  -- **Tags**  --  **Users**   --Space (about the width of the logo)--   **Badges** -- **Unanswered** -- **Ask Question**

As for what the tabs should loo like, I think they should look like a rectangle, I think the color should be light brown.

### Background Color

I think the back ground color should be beige. Perhaps a color a yellowish color which you may sometimes find in a Quran:

[image]

as for the:

### Voting Buttons

I believe [yasar11732 's](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/412/9) suggestion is excellent for the design of the voting buttons:

[image]

Comment: Only Allah without praise? why not Subhanallah, Allahuakbar...