# Islam site design and logo — Draft

Tags: discussion, design

Salaam alaikum, Islam Stack Exchange community! I'm V2Blast, a Community Manager here at Stack Exchange; I'm also working with the design team on the site themes project alongside Catija. I first want to thank you for your patience and apologize that it's taken so long to get back to you all after [our initial post here](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3576/custom-islam-stack-exchange-design-and-logo-information-gathering).

Below you'll find the proposed site theme for Islam Stack Exchange that our designers came up with based on your original ideas, alongside some explanations from the designer (in their own words) about their design choices. We wanted to take special care in crafting this site's design, given the subject matter, and we hope you like it!

---

### Your site design

We want to give you your own theme that reflects your topic, culture, and community. While all sites on the network share common elements, this design will help brand and celebrate your unique community.

### Color scheme

[image: Proposed color palette for the Islam Stack Exchange site, incorporating 6 colors: red, gold, green, gray, black, and white.]

The color choices for our proposed theme reflect significant colors in Islam. The sacred color of green, adornments of gold in the Qur'an, red on many Muslim-majority country flags, and the black stone walls of the Kaaba. These serve as the foundation for the logo and various other elements in this theme.

### Logo & identity

The site's name is set in a subtly calligraphic contemporary serif font. We have two proposed logos for this site — a star and crescent, or a simplified version of the Kaaba:

[image: Proposed logo (option 1) for the Islam Stack Exchange site and its Meta, as described above. The main site icon shows a red star and crescent, with the text "Islam" in black to the right of the icon. The meta site logo is similar, but in grayscale and with the word "Meta" in gray to the right of the word "Islam".]

[image: Proposed logo (option 2) for the Islam Stack Exchange site and its Meta, as described above. The main site icon shows a simplified depiction of the kaaba in black, with the text "Islam" in black to the right of the icon. The meta site logo is similar, but the icon is gray (and the word "Meta" appears in gray to the right of the word "Islam", as above).]

We would appreciate any feedback from users on this choice, as choosing a single icon to reflect as complex and storied a faith as Islam can be difficult. If anyone has ideas for a more reflective and fitting symbol for this community, please share them in an answer below.

### Overall site design

Here are some examples of how the main and Meta site might look with this design (click each image to view full-size):

[image: Proposed page design/style, showing the main site's Questions page (/questions). The header and footer are outlined in red; the background of the header is white, and the background of the footer is black. A green geometric pattern tiled below the top bar, and a different geometric pattern is tiled throughout the background in between. Question titles and other links appear in light green (or black for visited links), while regular tags appear with a yellow background.]
[image: Proposed page design/style, showing a question page on the main site.]
[image: Proposed page design/style, showing the Meta site's Questions page. The colors have been changed to grayscale; the header and footer are outlined in dark gray, the geometric pattern tiled below the top bar is black, and unvisited links are light gray.]

### Thoughts?

We hope you enjoy this design, but if something doesn't feel right, now is your chance to share your feedback. This window for feedback will be open for two weeks. We will then work to incorporate feedback as best as we can, finalize things on our end, and lastly, deliver the design to your site.

Comment: Might help to include examples that show how questions with ignored/highlighted tags would appear, and how the voting arrows would look when selected.

Comment: Okay my VPN works again!  (Sorry I'm late.)  First of all: nice work!  It's not my eyes, right?  (Or a JPEG artifact?)  There's a subtle paper-like background texture.  I like the idea of the Kabaa, but I'm worried this design might be confused for a badge or company logo.  goldPseudo's point notwithstanding, out of these two logos, I slightly prefer the star and crescent (but honestly, both are good options).

Comment: Update: [Your new site design is live!](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3649/46770)

Answer (score 4):

First of all many thanks for your efforts!

As a person with relationships to Morocco "*I'd love*" to see the design that @UmH regarded as "ugly" since it includes both colors of that countries flag. But this could create a problem that's why I suggest adding some colors and making it more colorful.

#### Logo and identity

I'm more in favor of the Kaaba symbol for the same reasons @goldPseudo listed.

#### Color scheme

your choices clearly show your research effort, but in general there's neither a restriction nor a recommendation for a specific color in Islam. On the other hand Muslims artists or designers used much abstraction mosaics in order to come over the prohibition of painting anything that has a soul or shadow. That's why I need to ask whether adding a color or two would be an issue: My suggestion would be "blue" and I'm also somewhat missing "gold" a bit.

#### My suggestions for an overall design

(This was just roughly done with paint just to have a first shot)
**Simple change** Basically your presented design with small squares in blue and gold instead of having the mosaic all in green:
[image]
If adding blue isn't an option at least using "gold" here could do!

**Colorful change**: A bit more color changes (green is more dominant than red as in the presented design):

[image]

My point is the mosaic should include more colors to avoid the issue of being biased. And maybe @UmH would find one of these less "ugly".

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! We incorporated some of your suggestions into [the final design](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3649/46770). We hope you like it!

Answer (score 2):

At a quick first impression, I like it.

Given the choice, I would definitely prefer the Kaaba icon; while I appreciate that the [star-and-crescent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_and_crescent) has become the de-facto symbol of Islam around the world, I've always found it problematic since it's not actually something that originated with the Prophet. Even if the Kaaba is less globally recognized by non-Muslims, it's still one of the few things that's acknowledged as a unifying Islamic symbol in *all* schools of Islam, which I think is an important consideration for a pluralistic site like ours.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The red lines looks kinda ugly to me. The meta design looks much better, I might even suggest making that the design for the main site:

[image]

As for the logo, I am fine with either of them.

Comment: This design mostly aligns with Turkey flag (color flipped).